# Deleting an object from array of objects based on values of entire object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects containing ids that look like this:

```
selectedParameters = [
{
 operationID: "5f1def6a3f15e2fde38d8b13",
 operatorID: "5f241ea9a28f1a5700bfb82a"
},
{
 operationID: "5f1def6a3f15e2fde38d8b13",
 operatorID: "5f241ea9a28f1a5700bfb829"
},
{
 operationID: "5f1def6a3f15e2fde38d8b13",
 operatorID: "5f241ea9a28f1a5700bfb828"
},
{
 operationID: "5f1def7c3f15e2fde38d8b14",
 operatorID: "5f241ea9a28f1a5700bfb82a"
},
{
 operationID: "5f1def7c3f15e2fde38d8b14",
 operatorID: "5f241ea9a28f1a5700bfb829"
},
]
```

I have a method which takes in an object having exact properties like above and then I want to check both operationID and operatorID of incoming object and delete that object from above array on exact match. I have a method that attempted to do that as shown below:

```
const deleteSelectedParameter = (removedParamObj) => {
   selectedParameters.filter(
        (selectedParam) =>
          (selectedParam.operationID !==
            removedParamObj.operationID) &&
          (selectedParam.operatorID !== removedParamObj.operatorID)
      )
  };
```

However, I upon deleting it deletes multiple objects even though only one matches.

Comment: `upon deleting it` - your code doesn't delete anything - perhaps you're *doing it wrong™* - hard to say what you do wrong, since that's the code you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX Array.filter() is a valid way to delete elements.

Comment: @cyqsimon-- not quite-- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) _creates a new array_; it doesn't mutate the original array.  Since `deleteSelectedParameter` isn't returning the new array, I suspect that the poster believes it to be mutative when it is in fact not.

Comment: @cyqsimon - yes ... if **USED CORRECTLY** (which it isn't for the above reason) - at the moment, there's no way of knowing how the code in the function is being used - which was my point - there's no code that **deletes** anything

Comment: I wonder if the phrase `it deletes multiple objects` was meant to be `it deletes EVERYTHING`

Comment: @AlexanderNied I am aware of that. Thanks for clarifying though. However I think it's clear that OP knows this too, based on the fact that he is "deleting" anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some error in the binary logic. You can try the following code:

const deleteSelectedParameter = (removedParamObj) => {

```
   return selectedParameters.filter(
        (selectedParam) =>
         !((selectedParam.operationID === removedParamObj.operationID) && (selectedParam.operatorID === removedParamObj.operatorID))
    )
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic binary logic error.

What you want for `filter()`'s callback is this:

return false if opID equals and operID equals.

Which is `return == !(opIDEq && operIDEq) == opIDNeq || operIDNeq`.

What you did was `return == operIDNeq && operIDNeq`.

So basically, change your `&&` to `||`.

Comment: making that change won't change the fact that **nothing is deleted**

Comment: OP is clearly writing a function that returns an array that does not contain the designated element. Maybe you should try to infer the intentions instead of rejecting something solely based on inaccurate word choice.

Comment: OP is clearly writing a function *that doesn't return anything* - you need to re-read the code before making such statements ... `() => {statement}` returns undefined ... `()=>statement` returns result of statement ... `() => {return statement}` returns the result of statement

Comment: So... Maybe he simply forgot to put a `return` before `filter()` for the example code? That's not important bit. The important bit is that his filter callback is incorrect.

Comment: clearly, that would cause an issue - resulting in `undefined` result - if you want to *assume* the OP's code is not the code he's having problems with, that's fine too

Comment: OP stated that the issue he's having is NOT `undefined`, rather more things are being deleted than he wishes. He just needs someone to fix his issue, not to nitpick at a technicality in his example code, which is probably just an error while selecting which small part of his real code he should paste here as example. The fact that he's deleting something at all shows that he understands how basic things like `return` and `filter()` work. I don't understand what has led you to believe that this is the key problem.

Comment: I look at the code in the question - since the description of the problem is vague at best, and the OP doesn't even bother to show how the code in the question is being used, and even if he is using it like *you* suggest, he's not **deleting** anything - he's simply attempting to create a new array with less elements than the original array - this is NOT deleting, this is filtering